# Close opencv contours

Tags: opencv, computer-vision, contour

I would like to enclose the below contours. Does anyone have any suggestions?

[image]

Comment: [Morphological Operations](https://docs.opencv.org/3.4/d9/d61/tutorial_py_morphological_ops.html). Try filtering with a vertical and horizontal structuring element.

Comment: Could you provide an example image?

Comment: Any other solution rather than Morphological Operations?

Comment: https://xyproblem.info/ you aren't sharing the real problem.